# Why EDEADLK is not returned for consecutive pthread_mutex_lock even though ERRORCHECK is enabled?

Tags: c++, concurrency, pthreads, mutex, errno

I am experimenting with pthread API and would like to understand something.

As per my understanding, following code should generate EDEADLK error code but I am getting undefined error:

```
mutex lock: : Undefined error: 0
```

```
void case3_error_checking_mutex()
{
  pthread_mutexattr_t attr;
  pthread_mutexattr_init(&attr);
  pthread_mutexattr_settype(&attr, PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK);

  pthread_mutex_t mtx;
  pthread_mutex_init(&mtx, &attr);
  pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
  if (pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx) != 0) {
      perror("mutex lock: ");
      return;
  }
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mtx);
}
```

Any ideas?

Thank you!

PS: I know what is recursive mutex, I know what is deadlock, I know this is ugly code etc. Please do not comment on such stuff. This is purely experimental code for me to better understand details of pthread API.

Comment: Have you checked the values returned by other functions -- pthread_mutexattr_settype etc.?  Is the mutex type `PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK` available on the platform (I seem to recall certain aspects of the `pthread` API were optional)?

Comment: @G.M. I checked the settype, it does not return error. If PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK does not available, it won't compile.

Comment: @G.M. OK I found that error is returned via return value not errno, that is the reason we do not see any valid info with perror.

Answer (score 2):

I found that errno is not set. Following solves the problem.

```cpp
const int ret = pthread_mutex_lock(&mtx);
if (ret != 0) {
   errno = ret;
   perror("mutex lock: ");
   return;
}
```

```
mutex lock: : Resource deadlock avoided
```

Comment: Note that this is true of all pthread functions - they all return error number (errno) on failure and 0 on success.

Comment: @P.P Thank you. It was kind of surprising to me but still my bad, had to read doc carefully.